# Classical analog of Bell QM experiment correlation coefficient calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, experimental-physics, classical-electrodynamics, polarization

This question is motivated by recent experiments in QM entanglement.[1][2] consider the following "simple/ simplified" *classical analog* of Bells experiment. it has a laser, a standard beamsplitter reflecting light in 2 directions "left/ right", and 2 polarizing beamsplitters, 1 at each left/ right arm. This creates 4 separate rays fed to 4 light detectors. 1 of the arms has a rotation angle relative to the other "θ".

Now consider a twist on the detection. The detectors measure light intensity, but convert it to binary on/off measurements ("pulses") based on a threshhold value T.

There is another twist. There is a motorized rotating polarizer screen in front of the laser prior to the 1st standard beamsplitter. It rotates at a constant speed.

The standard correlation coefficent for the Bell experiment is E(θ) = R<sub>++</sub> + R<sub>--</sub> - R<sub>-+</sub> - R<sub>+-</sub> (where Rs are coincident pulses at opposite ends as in standard experiments).

In this experiment, E(θ) is calculated based on the detector threshhold measurements over short time Δt, counted/ integrated over long time scales/ many repeated measurements.

> what is the formula for E(θ) (calculated using classical physics)?

note: can foresee there are some hidden subtlety(s) in calculating this formula.

[1] [Quantum computer emulated by a classical system](https://phys.org/news/2015-05-quantum-emulated-classical.html) / La Cour, Ott, physorg

[2] [Spooky Experiments Bring Quantum Weirdness to Nearly Macroscopic Scales](https://gizmodo.com/spooky-experiments-bring-quantum-weirdness-to-nearly-ma-1825571168/amp) / Gizmodo

Comment: What's the classical analog of entanglement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand difficulty of violating Bell inequalities, it is better to look at this one ([page 9 here](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/notes/chap4.pdf)) for binary variables $A,B,C$:

$$P(A=B)+P(A=C)+P(B=C) \geq 1$$

It can be easily checked by assigning any probability distribution among 8 possibilities, or just: "drawing 3 coins, 2 of them have to give the same value".

However, it is violated in QM.

To do it, instead of standard: "*probability of alternative of disjoint events is sum of their probabilities*" leading to above inequality,

we need to use **Born rules**: "*probability of alternative of disjoint events is proportional to **square** of sum of their amplitudes*".

Such Born rule can be easily understood if instead of ensemble of events in a given moment, like in Feynman path integrals we use ensemble of paths ([discussion](http://www.sciphysicsforums.com/spfbb1/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=318)). This way amplitude corresponds to probability at the end of past or future half-paths, to draw some value in a given moment we need to draw it from both time directions, getting $P\propto \psi^2$ Born rule.